# Writing Hive ACID events to the delta files

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to find how an ACID event is composed and written to a delta file.  Could someone direct me to the Hive code where this is done?

Answer (score 0):

addEvent in org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater